# div to 100% height not working

Tags: html, css

I know that there are many other similar posts, however this is my case and its just not working with the solutions provided on the above mentioned posts.

This is my CSS in regards to HTML, body and the div tag that I want to stretch in height, the div id container is the first element on page after the body tag:

```
    body {
    height:100%;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:10pt;
    color:#000000;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    html { 
    height:100%;
    background: url(./images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='./images/background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    }
    div#container
    {        
    height:100%;
    width:650px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;   
    position:relative; 

    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #222222;
    border-left: 4px solid #ff6633;
    border-right: 4px solid #3366ff;    
    background-color:#ffffff;
    background-image:url(./images/header.jpg);
    background-size:auto;
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;        
    }
```

This is the relevant HTML on my MasterPage file:

```
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">       
            <div id="container">          
                <div id="header">
                    <!-- here goes my header image and text -->
                </div>  

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphBody" runat="server"/>

                <div id="menu">
                    <!-- here goes my menu links in a line -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: what is your problem? Show also your html

Comment: @elnath78 post your `HTML` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `form` wrapping your container:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">       
        <div id="container">          
            <div id="header">
                <!-- here goes my header image and text -->
            </div>  

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphBody" runat="server"/>

            <div id="menu">
                <!-- here goes my menu links in a line -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

You need to set the height property for `#form1` to 100%.

See strip-down example below in the snippet.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#form1 {
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  border-left: 2px dotted blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      header...
    </div>

    ContentPlaceHolder...

    <div id="menu">
      menu
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks! setting form height just resolved the issue. never though form would be considered as a nesting element such as a div would be.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to stretch the height to exactly the visible area regardless of setting a min height?

Try to set the height of the container in "vh" rather than in %, e.g. `height:100vh;`

Comment: yes with vh was working just fine, but it is not being recognized by android browser, so I had to change.

Comment: Unfortunately, browser compatibility is sometimes an issue with CSS3, despite all its beauty and flexibility

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="container">          
        <div id="header">
            <!-- here goes my header image and text -->
            lorem
        </div>  

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphBody" runat="server"/>

        <div id="menu">
            <!-- here goes my menu links in a line -->
            lorem
        </div>
    </div>

 #container{
height: 100%;
width:650px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;   
    position:relative; 
overflow: hidden;
}

#header, #menu{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `#wrapp` not specific enough for you?

Comment: He want to stretch the div for me is enough :) What is wrong with my code manipulate with min-height you can strech the div as you want :)

Comment: what if for some reason the window height is 600px? is it possible to stretch the height to exactly the visible area regardless of setting a min height?

Comment: How you want stretch your div#wrapp without any content inside ? if height of your window will be smaler you will see overflow-y to scroll simple what exactly you want to do ???

Comment: the div content is the placeholder, so each page will put its own content; see my original post I have added other elements to the wrapper contents.

Comment: the other two divs must not be 100% height, only the container and the elements inside should resize accordingly to their own content.